I can't connect to my websocket OpenAi to my websocket in my Twilio script?
Whenever I run this script on a live server i get the message from Twilio 'ok you can start talking', then it just hangs up. I believe there's an issue with OpenAI connecting to my nginx VPS web server URL? This what happens when i run my python script.
`INFO: Started server process [8276]
INFO: Waiting for application startup.
INFO: Application startup complete.
INFO: Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:5050 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
here

Please wait while we connect your call to the A. I. voice assistant, powered by Twilio and the Open-A.I. Realtime APIO.K. you can start talking!
INFO: 34.255.178.120:35938 - "POST /incoming-call HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
WARNING: Invalid HTTP request received.
WARNING: Invalid HTTP request received.
WARNING: Invalid HTTP request received.`

I'm getting invalid HTTP requests when i try to connect to this websocket. I've installed an SSL cert and forwarded univorn python to https. This is my nginx config
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name 45.133.178.x;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/45.133.178.x/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/45.133.178.x/privkey.pem;

location /media-stream {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
}

This is the actual code on the page...
@app.api_route("/incoming-call", methods=["GET", "POST"])
async def handle_incoming_call(request: Request):
    """Handle incoming call and return TwiML response to connect to Media Stream."""
    response = VoiceResponse()
    # <Say> punctuation to improve text-to-speech flow
    response.say("Please wait while we connect your call to the A. I. voice assistant, powered by Twilio and the Open-A.I. Realtime API")
    response.pause(length=1)
    response.say("O.K. you can start talking!")
    host = request.url.hostname
    connect = Connect()
    connect.stream(url=f'wss://{host}/media-stream')
    response.append(connect)
    return HTMLResponse(content=str(response), media_type="application/xml")

@app.websocket("/media-stream")
async def handle_media_stream(websocket: WebSocket):
    """Handle WebSocket connections between Twilio and OpenAI."""
    print("Client connected")
    await websocket.accept()


after 'ok start talking' the call just hangs up
I installed an ssl certificate, updated nginx and reloaded and forwarded http to https. i'm using wscat to test the websocket. I've changed the response.pause(length=60), it just hangs up after 60 secs.
